# The Fundamental Group - An explicit homotopy between $(f \circ g) \circ h$ and $f \circ (g \circ h)$

Tags: general-topology

I'm wondering if anyone can help me to understand a proof that the fundamental group is in fact a group. I am looking at the proof on page 3 of [this document](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Landau.pdf).

I understand everything, although I am struggling to get to grips with the associativity part. I can't understand where the explicit homotopy between $(f \bullet g) \bullet r$  and $f \bullet (g \bullet r)$ comes from.

$h(t,s) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{f((2s)t + (4s)(1 − t))} & 0 \leq s \leq (\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1-t}{4}) \\
       \text{g(4s-2)} & (\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1-t}{4}) \leq s \leq (\frac{3t}{4}+\frac{1-t}{2}) \\
       \text{r((4s − 3)t + (2s − 1)(1 − t))} & (\frac{3t}{4}+\frac{1-t}{2}) \leq s \leq 1 \\
     \end{cases}$

If anyone can help me understand where this is derived from, that would be great. I'm led to believe that sketching the homotopy in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ would help, but I can't seem to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This explicit formula is actually wrong. For example, for $s = 1/4$ and $t = 0$ you get $g(-1)$, which is not defined. If I'm not mistaken, one should replace the value of the second case with $g(4s + t - 2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the standard picture of the homotopy:

[image]

Can you figure out the formula for $H$ from it?

Comment: I guess it's something to do with the simple linear equations of the lines going between $(f \bullet g) \bullet r$  and $f \bullet (g \bullet r)$. However I can't match them up with the bounds on s.

Comment: Scratch that! I get it. So $t$ is moving down the y axis, as $s$ is moving along the x axis. Then the bounds on $s$ are just the equations of the 2 lines going down the homotopy if you write them in the form $s = f(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

The equality has little to do with the space $X$, but only with how $\bullet$ is defined.
If $f,g$ are defined on $[0,1]$, we define $f\bullet g$ by "squeezing" $f$ and $g$ to $[0,\frac12]$ and $[\frac12,1]$. Consequently, when combining $f,g,h$, one variant has squeezed versions of the function on $[0,\frac14]$, $[\frac14,\frac12]$, $[\frac12,1]$ and the other on  $[0,\frac12]$, $[\frac12,\frac34]$, $[\frac34,1]$. The trick to show associativity now is to shift the joints $\frac14$, $\frac12$ continuously to the right so that they end up at $\frac12$ and $\frac34$. So the combined curve doesn't move along $X$ at all in the homotopy constructed, rather we merely modify the "schedule" how fast we walk along its three segments.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this much. What I'm confused about is how to derive the explicit homotopy I quoted in the question.